# Object c# доступ к встроенным типам

Tags: c#

Товарищи, подскажите, пожалуйста

```
static void Main()
    {
        object [] A = new string[3] { "1", "2", "3" };
        Console.WriteLine(A[1]);
    }
```

Почему выводится значение 1 индекса? Ведь по идее оно не должно выводиться, так как object это всего лишь базовый класс, а string производный от него. Но базовый класс не имеет доступа к элементам производного, кроме тех которые сами были унаследованы от базового. То есть получается, что обжект не должен получить доступ к массиву.

Вот здесь, например правильно получается, что нет доступа

```
using System;
    class a
    {
        public int x = 9;
    }
    class b : a
    {
        public new int x = 88;
    }
    class c : b
    {
        public new int x = 388;
    }
    class d
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            object a = new c();
            Console.WriteLine(a.x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: а в чем противоречие-то? В первом случае вы не обращаетесь ни как каким методам вообще - ни к методам потомков, ни к методам предков, и все работает.
Во втором случае вы объявляете **a** как **object**, а затем пытаетесь работать с ним как с классом **с**. Хотя фактически ваша переменная **a** является экземпляром **c**, компилятор об этом не знает, поскольку вы объявили ее как **object**. Все логично

Comment: Такой вопрос - зачем вообще нужна ковариация массивов?

Comment: >Такой вопрос - зачем вообще нужна ковариация массивов?

@Veikedo а к кому адресован этот вопрос? Если к ТС, то в его случае скорее всего она была применена неосознанно в рамках примера

Comment: @DreamChild, ни к кому конкретно. Просто лирическое отступление :)

Comment: @Veikedo ну если в рамках лирического отступления, то против ковариации массивов небезосновательно высказывался такой небезызвестный товарищ, как Эрик Липперт, дескать, она ослабляет безопасность типов. Впрочем, сейчас ее никто уже из языка не выпилит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вызывается метод Object.ToString(), который кастит текущий объект в String. Но это в лоб и неправда.

А если честно, то там идеологически не верно вызывается полиморфный метод String.ToString().

Comment: Почему по-идиотски?

Comment: >вызывается метод Object.ToString(), который кастит текущий объект в String

я бы не стал утверждать, что в нем происходит приведение к **string**

Comment: @Veikedo
Потому что String.ToString() имеет мало смысла в себе. Не принимайте близко к сердцу, я фигурально и без злобы =)

Comment: @DreamChild

    > Но это в лоб и неправда.

=) MSDN с вами согласен.

Comment: эммм  @Free_ze не сочтите, что придираюсь, просто любопытно - в чем смысл писать и тут же опровергать мысль?

Comment: @DreamChild
Потому что пошел исследовать предмет дискуссии глубже и исправил сам себя) Но кто-то уже поспешил согласиться с моим ошибочным предположением, потому старый вариант не убрал, а подчеркнул его ошибочность.